# .append and fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, fadein

I append a div with a overlay effect like this:

```
$("body").append('<div class="overlay-white"><div>')
```

The overlay-white class. Have this css:

```
position                : absolute;
    top                     : 0;
    left                    : 0;
    width                   : 100%;
    height                  : 100%;
    z-index                 : 500;
    background              : url(../img/backgrounds/bg-overlay.png) repeat left top;
```

But now my problem. The overlay pops it now. But how can i fade in the overlay???

Answer (score 4):

```
var overlay = $('<div class="overlay-white"><div>');
overlay.hide().appendTo("body").fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").append('<div class="overlay-white"><div>');
$('.overlay-white').fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

first you may set the `overlay-white` like this `display : none;` in css

```
$("body").append('<div class="overlay-white"><div>')
```

then do like this .. `$('.overlay-white').fadeIn();`

hopefully help .